# Why does assignment in static init block compile without error?

Tags: java, initialization

I was experimenting on initialization order in Java and I came across something really confusing:

```
static {
    System.out.println("Static 1, staticField can't be accessed (compile error)");
    staticField = "value"; // NO COMPILE ERROR!
    //System.out.println(staticField); // compile error
}

public static String staticField;

static {
    System.out.println("Static 2, staticField=" + staticField); // prints "value"
}
```

As you can see, we cannot reference a field that was not declared yet, hence the compile error on `System.out.println(staticField);` in the first static block:

> Cannot reference a field before it is defined.

However, **it is possible** to assign such a field, as we can tell from the value in the second static block.

Why is this so?

Comment: i think that the compilier read all static variable reference before executing static blocks

Comment: @karim yes, but the question is *if the variable is defined, why cannot be used after it's declaration but it can be initialized?*

Comment: @karim Static fields initializations and static init blocks are executed in the source order according to Java documentation. However I found nothing about the declarations themselves (as opposed to the initialization). Anyway, if the fields declarations were read before, then why would read access be impossible while write access is?

Comment: The rule about declaring a variable before referencing it only really applies to local variables.

Comment: @Hot Licks Then why is there a compile error on the `System.out.println(staticField);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour is listed in [JLS §8.3.2.3 - Restrictions on the use of Fields during Initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3):

> The declaration of a member needs to appear textually before it is
>   used only if the member is an instance (respectively static) field of
>   a class or interface C and all of the following conditions hold:
>
> - The usage occurs in an instance (respectively static) variable
>     initializer of C or in an instance (respectively static) initializer
>     of C.
> - The usage is not on the left hand side of an assignment.
> - The usage is via a simple name.
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the usage.
>
> It is a compile-time error if any of the four requirements above are
>   not met.

Basically, when you are accessing a `static` field on its simple name on left hand side of an expression, the declaration should not be done before it, as per the second rule. However, using it on the right hand side of an assignment, or trying to use its value in an expression, then you need to declare it beforehand, else it is a compiler error.

In other words, you can assign any value to those fields, but cannot use their value on simple name, which is what you're trying to do in the print statement.

Of course, **if you use the field using the qualified name, then it would work**. So, the following code would compile:

```
static {
    System.out.println("Static 1, staticField can't be accessed (compile error)");
    staticField = "value"; // NO COMPILE ERROR!
    System.out.println(Main.staticField); // compiles fine now
}
```

Comment: I see. But it is weird that we need a fully qualified name while in the class declaring the field.

Comment: @Joffrey Some things are there which we can't reason about, and the reason is simply, because the language was designed like that. I'm not the right person to comment upon whether this is correct or not. It may seem weird on first look, but you will get used to such rules. There are so many of them. And luckily, you can almost always find the reason in JLS :)

Comment: Yeah, true ^^ I guess some of the reasons are there to simplify the compiler. Thanks for the answer anyway!